# Нет перевода текста в окне подтверждения при голосовании за переоткрытие вопросы из очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок, причины-закрытия

При попытке проголосовать за переоткрытие вопроса в очереди появляется модальное окно, в котором не переведены строки.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]