# Неполный перевод диалога в очереди на повторное открытие

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок, переоткрытие-вопросов

При нажатии на кнопку «Переоткрыть» появляется диалоговое окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дефекты:

1. Основной текст и кнопка — на английском языке, то есть не переведены;
2. Заголовок окна сформулирован как вопрос, хотя традиционно такие заголовки оформляют как повествовательную фразу без завершающих знаков препинания;
3. Отсутствие единой терминологии — «переоткрыть»/«повторное открытие» (кнопка в очереди/заголовок окна).

Необходимо добавить перевод, если это новые строки, либо восстановить старые, если перевод уже был, но слетел.

Идентификаторы строк в Traducir:

- заголовок окна: [9202](https://ru.traducir.win/string/9202)

  > Nominate this question for reopening?
- основной текст: [13821](https://ru.traducir.win/string/13821)

  > Vote to reopen questions that have been improved or shouldn’t have been closed on $siteName$. $startLink$Learn more$endLink$ about reopening questions.
- кнопка окна: [13826](https://ru.traducir.win/string/13826)

  > Vote to reopen
- кнопка в очереди закрытия: [7205](https://ru.traducir.win/string/7205)

  > Reopen

Comment: На момент написания вопроса не увидел, что Suvitruf [тоже обратил внимание на этот диалог](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9744/208074) пять часов назад. Но здесь приведено больше деталей, так что удалять пока не буду.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По содержимому диалога предлагаю следующее (исправив ссылку вида «нажмите здесь»):

1. Заголовок:

   > Голосование за повторное открытие вопроса

   или

   > Голосование за переоткрытие вопроса
2. Тело:

   > Голосуйте за открытие только тех вопросов, которые были исправлены, либо не подходят под критерии закрытия на $siteName$. Подробнее о процедуре написано в разделе справки «$startLink$Как задавать вопросы$endLink$».
3. Кнопка:

   > Проголосовать

Выглядеть это будет так:

[image]

Comment: А чего не сразу в традусёра? UPD. В целом, утвердил переводы.